# Qualcomm Atheros AR9462 with Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: networking, drivers, atheros

I can't enable the Wifi (nothing happens when press enable button) and in Wifi settings it says:

> "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found"

I have tried several things from other questions/answers here but nothing worked. Here some information if this is helpful for the answer:

> Device: Lenovo Miix 2 11

`sudo lspci`:

```
Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

`sudo lshw -C network`:

```
*-network DISABLED        
   description: Wireless interface
   product: AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlp2s0
   version: 01
   serial: 48:d2:24:8a:ea:e6
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.18.0-16-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:18 memory:f0400000-f047ffff memory:f0480000-f048ffff
```

`sudo lsmod | grep ath`:

```
ath3k                  20480  0
bluetooth             548864  12 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,ath3k,btusb
ath9k                 151552  0
ath9k_common           36864  1 ath9k
ath9k_hw              475136  2 ath9k_common,ath9k
ath                    36864  3 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath9k_hw
mac80211              794624  1 ath9k
cfg80211              663552  5 wl,ath9k_common,ath9k,ath,mac80211
```

In system settings it shows the Wifi-Adapter Name:

```
Qualcomm Atheros AR9462
```

Edit:

`lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0034] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Lenovo AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:3214]
Kernel driver in use: ath9k
Kernel modules: ath9k, wl
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
2: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: yes
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your wireless adapter is blocked by `rfkill`.

You can fix it by running

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ideapad.conf <<< "blacklist ideapad_laptop"
```

Reboot to apply.

You can always revert this blacklist by

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ideapad.conf
```

Comment: Thx it worked :-)