# Cant get wifi drivers to work

Tags: drivers, intel, iwlwifi

I'm trying to get the wifi drivers for my laptop to work on Ubuntu 18.04. I followed steps to install them, but the settings still say "No WiFi adapter found. Make sure you have a wifi driver turned on. Bluetooth does work though after installing the drivers.

Running dmesg | grep iwl returns me this:

dmesg | grep iwl

```
[   16.154000] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 38.c0e03d94.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[   16.166883] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 9560, REV=0x318
[   16.217152] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: base HW address: 18:1d:ea:5e:58:94
[   16.286771] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[   16.287614] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3 wlp0s20f3: renamed from wlan0
```

and lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list returns this

```
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak] [8086:a370] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0034]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: yes
2: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

Does anyone have a clue what I'm doing wrong? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1124020/167850